# How to fix error in React(functional component). "Signup Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'protocol')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My teammate and I built this multi-step sign-up form where all the data that was input by the user is presented at the end. Once the user clicks on the submit button to create the user account, I get the error, Signup Error:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'protocol') on the console. How can I fix this? This is my code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const UserSignUpReview = (props) => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState(null);
    const user = props.location.state.user;
    const firstName = props.location.state.firstName;
    const lastName = props.location.state.lastName;
    const email = props.location.state.email;
    const username = props.location.state.username;
    console.log(props);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(username);

    const createAccount = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            setUserData(userData)
            const response = await axios.post(userData) 
            console.log(response.data)
            sessionStorage.setItem("user", response.data);
            props.push({
                pathname: '/UserAccount',
                state: {
                    user: response.data,
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    email: email,
                    username: username,
                },
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Signup Error: ", err.toString());
        }

    } 

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>

            <p>
                Create your account, and with a just a few easy steps you can save a
                horse a today.
            </p>

            <img src='' alt='' />

            <h2>Contact Info</h2>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>First Name: {firstName}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Last Name: {lastName}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Email: {email}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Username: {username}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Primary Phone Number: {user.primaryPhone}</p>
            </div>

            {user?.secondaryPhone && (
                <div className='review-content'>
                    <p>Secondary Phone Number: {user.secondaryPhone}</p>
                </div>
            )}
            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Address: {user.address}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                {user?.addressTwo && <p>Address #2: {user.addressTwo}</p>}
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>City: {user.city}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>State: {user.state}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Zip Code: {user.zipCode}</p>
            </div>

            <h2>Details</h2>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>About you: {user.questionnaire[0].aboutYou}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>
                    Previous experience with horses: {user.questionnaire[0].previousExperienceWithHorses}
                </p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Children at Home: {user.questionnaire[0].childrenAtHome}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='review-content'>
                <p>Pets at home: {user.questionnaire[0].otherPetsAtHome}</p>
            </div>

            <h2>Documents</h2>

            <p>Attached Forms: {user.docUpload[0].photoID}</p>

            <img src='' alt='' />

            <button type='submit'
                        onClick={createAccount}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserSignUpReview;
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are calling `setUserData(userData)` on only the `createAccount` method which means you are setting it to it's default value of `null`.

This means that you are sending `null` as the first argument in `axios.post`. Axios requires that you include the url as the first parameter for `axios.post()` else it will throw a protocol area.

Comment: Oh! Does this mean that the URL that is required can be a relative path towards the user account I am trying to create?

Comment: Yes though it depends. Is the POST URL you are trying to send is in the same domain as your form?

Comment: I am uncertain by what you mean when you say the same domain as my form. What I am trying to do is create a user account from the information that was put into the login form.